# Triggering a function when error occurs in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling

How can I trigger a function when a command in bash returns an exit code of 1?  I know `set -e` at the top will just make my code terminate, but I want to call this function first.  If the code runs ok I want it to exit normally without the function being called.  I don't want to do a `$?` check after every line.  I'm sure there's an easy way to do this but I'm new to bash scripting so I don't know it offhand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a trap on the `ERR` pseudosignal:

```
set -e
error_handler () {
    # do stuff here
}

trap error_handler ERR
```

Comment: So the ERR pseudosignal is fired any time a 1 exit status is returned from a failed command?

Comment: Almost any time. There are a few exceptions that make sense (if the failed command is not the last command in an `&&` or `||` list, for example).